# django-autocomplete-light and related manager

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I need to make fields with autocomplete for my custom forms. It's just a drop-down menu with matched cities, countries etc. I also use django-cities for that. So, I subclassed AutocompleteModelBase. Here, I can declare search_fields attribute with list of fields from model, on which the search will be applied. But what if I want to search not by the fields, but by, for example, info from related managers? In django-cities, there is special related manager for so-called alternative names. It returns queryset with names for some geo object in 
foreign languages. Something like this: `Country.objects.get(code='US').alt_names.filter(language='de')`

So, I need to search by the results of such operations. Not by the fields of the model, but by translated names, which don't belong to actually fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [any queryset you want](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/v2/autocomplete.html#overriding-the-queryset-of-a-model-autocomplete-to-secure-an-autocomplete).